# How to batch zip multiple files in one .zip file

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 csv files

file1.csv  and file2.csv

I want to zip them into zipfile.zip with batch

how can I do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Linux/Unix environment, you can use tar + gzip from command line.

In Windows, you can use software like 7-Zip. Here a simple guide:

[Useful 7-Zip batch examples in Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20140115081956/http://www.flocked.net/topic/computing/item/475-useful-7-zip-batch-examples-in-windows) [Archived]

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
wzzip -a yourzipfilename file1.csv file2.csv
```